# Can I use the command line again while a Java program is running?

Tags: shell, command-line, command

For example, say I run a program from the command line called foo.java using the command "java foo".

foo.java just happens to be a game, and it runs continuously. Until foo.java is finished running, I don't know how to use the command line again unless I type ctrl + c. But this terminates the foo.java program that's currently running. Can I use the command line again without terminating foo.java first? If so, how?

Comment: That depends on your shell.  In bash, for example, you can just run `java foo &` and execute it as a background task.

Comment: This is really more of a user question than a programming one.  Take a look at [How can I execute a windows command in background?](http://superuser.com/questions/198525/how-can-i-execute-a-windows-command-line-in-background) over on superuser.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your shell, you can probably do `java foo&` to run the process in the background (this is not specific to Java), or you can background an already-in-the-foreground process with `CTRL+Z` (suspend, which pauses the process), and then `bg`, which resumes the paused process in the background.

You can also use `fg` to do the opposite: once you backgrounded a process you can bring it back to the front again with `fg`.

You can do all of these things with arbitrarily-many processes at once. Read more about [job control](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html).

Comment: This works! Thank you.

Comment: @Solomon You're welcome. See my edit for more details: you can do some rather funky things with job control.

Answer (score 0):

Under Unix or Linux, you can run `java foo &` to tell the shell to give you a prompt back straight away ("running it in the background"). If the program is generating output to the console, though, that will interfere with your session because it will spray straight onto your screen; in bash, you might prefer `java foo >/dev/null 2>&1 &` - which means "redirect stdout to /dev/null (throw it away), redirect stderr to same place, in the background".

Alternatively, if the program is already started, you can do `ctrl-Z` to STOP the program (pause it), and then run the shell's `bg` command to continue it in the background.

If you are running under Windows, you can launch the program with `start java foo` - this launches a new dedicated command window for your program so you can carry on with the old one. Alternatively, you can use `start/x java foo` to do same, but with no new command window. Use `help start` to see more options.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Windows and you don't need the console output of your java application, you could use `javaw Foo` instead of `java Foo` and get your console back right away while having the java app running as well.